# iOSでプッシュ通知の証明書を.p12形式でexportしようとしたら.p12形式が選択できない

Tags: ios, push-notification

iOSでプッシュ通知の証明書を **.p12形式**でexportしようとしたら **.p12形式**が選択できないです。.p12形式を選択できなくなるのはどういった場合でしょうか？

[image: 当該証明書をエクスポートしようとした時の画面]

環境：

- Yosemite

Comment: @unarist 開いているアプリケーションは Keychain Access ですし、Xcode はこの質問に関係ないように見えますが

Comment: @quesera2 おっと、すみません。（iOSに限らない）Xcode全般の話題かと勘違いしてました。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

証明書に対応する秘密鍵はありますか?
ないとp12は選択できません。

Answer (score 1):

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

All Itemsか、検索からではなく、My Certificatesから選択してエクスポートすると.p12形式できると思います。

Answer (score 1):

4年も前の質問なのでとっくに解決したと思いますが、
同じような状況になったので回答します。

**解決法**

私の場合、証明書ファイルを書き出そうとして失敗していました。
証明書ではなく、秘密鍵（鍵マークのついたファイル）を書き出すことで解決します。

KeyChainのログインから、対応する秘密鍵を書き出せば .p12 を選択できます。

**補足：**
証明書を作るときに、証明書アシスタントの’通称’の欄に記入した名前がKeyの名前になっていました。