# 証明書がキーチェーンアクセスに登録されない

Tags: ios, push-notification

お世話になります

iosでプッシュ通知を使いたく、まずは証明書の登録を行っているのですが、うまくいかず、はまっております

ちょっと古いかもですが、以下を参考にやってるのですが
http://noboru.hatenablog.jp/entry/2013/09/28/195616

aps_development.cerをダブルクリックしても、キーチェーンアクセスの左ペインをログイン、証明書にしたところに出てこなく、（システム、証明書にはいる）p12ファイルの書き出しをしようとしても、p12ファイルの書き出しが選択が出来ずに困っております

どなたかご教授お願いします

Comment: "ログイン"の左にある鍵(南京錠)アイコンは開いていますか？開いてなければ、上にある少し大きい鍵アイコンをクリックするとパスワード入力で開けることができますよ。

Comment: そこは開いてるんですよね。。。秘密鍵がない状態ってことですかね

Comment: ログインのリスト中には証明書があるが、秘密鍵がない状態ってことですか？ならば、ita_3yさんの回答が役にたちそうですね。それと質問の意図を明確にするように編集をお勧めします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

うまく文面が読み取れておらず申し訳ないのですが、

> aps_development.cerをダブルクリックしても、キーチェーンアクセスの左ペーンをログイン、証明書したところに出てこなく、（システム、証明書にはいる）pemファイルの書き出しが出来ずに困っております

とは、そもそもキーチェーンアクセスに表示されないということでしょうか？
それとも、書き出す際に.p12形式が選択できないということでしょうか？

もし後者であれば、下記のチケットでbluedomeさんが記載してくださっているように、
証明書に対応する秘密鍵が必要になります。

[iOSでプッシュ通知の証明書を.p12形式でexportしようとしたら.p12形式が選択できない](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/1729)

Comment: 上記ありがとうございます
書き出す際にp12形式が選択できないですね。左ペインのキーチェーンのシステム、分類の証明書からですと、p12は書き出せないという記述をどこかのサイトで見つけました。左ペインのキーチェーンをログインにすると証明書が表示されないです。

Comment: つまりは、証明書に対応する秘密鍵がないということですかね

Comment: おそらくそうだと思います。秘密鍵があれば、キーチェーンアクセスで該当の証明書をクリックすると秘密鍵（鍵マーク）の行が表示されます。

Comment: なるほどです。秘密鍵がないという状況がちょっとよくわからないのですが、開発用の証明書の方は問題ないので、なぜなんだろうと思っています
これはどうしたらよいのでしょうか

Comment: 最初に証明書を要求したPCが別にありませんか？そのPCであれば秘密鍵が紐付いているのではないかと思います。http://dev.classmethod.jp/smartphone/ios-certificates/

Comment: 質問とは関係ありませんが、p12ファイルの取り扱いは慎重にしてください。身内以外の第三者には渡さないように。

Comment: @M.I.Aさん、そこは大丈夫です。個人開発なので自分以外は触りません

Comment: @ita_3yさん　開発証明書だけしか移行しなかったので、push通知の証明書は失念しておりました。。。移行してないです。。。

Comment: もし要求したPC側で処理できない状況なのであれば、再度要求からやりなおすのが早いかと思います。

Comment: 今回pushnotificationの証明書要求から行ってうまく行ってないのですが、やり直すのは、どこからでしょうか
開発用の証明書からでしょうか

Comment: 「pushnotificationの証明書要求から行って」とあるので的外れかもしれませんが、通常であればPush通知用にCSRの作成から再実施すれば問題ないと思います。

Comment: ですよね。。。何故うまく行かないんだろう。。。ちょっともう一度試してみます。ありがとうございます

Answer (score 0):

キーチェーンアクセスを1度終了してから再度起動すると反映される時があるようです。